# setting width calc with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

can someone help me properly add calc width with jquery? Or maybe theres a better option for dynamic width in jquery than applying css3 calc width?

```
var calc = "calc(100% - 270px)";

$(".two").focus(function () {
    $('.one').animate({ width: "85px" });
    $(this).animate({ "width": calc + "px" });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N6vaj/1/

Let me know if you need more description. Thanks~

Comment: You can't animate calc, only numerical regular css values can be animated. What exactly are you trying to do here ?

Comment: `calc` is a css property. You shouldn't do `calc + "px"` in your javascript, just leave it as `width:calc`. And I don't think it works with `animate`, either.

Comment: this is going to be a form on mobile so I want the width to be dynamic depending on container width / mobile device size. when a user clicks each input, all other inputs should get smaller to a point and the selected input should get bigger / fill up the remaining space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript `calc(100% - 270px)` would roughly equal getting the width of the parent element (100%) and subtracting 270

```
$(this).parent().width() - 270;
```

which leaves you with this

```
$(".two").focus(function () {
    var w = $(this).parent().width() - 270;

    $('.one').animate({ width: "85px" });
    $(this).animate({ "width": w });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/N6vaj/2/)

To make it work on all of them, you could do

```
var inputs = $(".one, .two, .three");

inputs.on('focus', function () {
    var w = $(this).parent().width() - 270;

    inputs.not(this).animate({ width: "85px" });
    $(this).animate({ "width": w });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/N6vaj/3/)

Comment: your right, 100% is technically talking about 100% of the parent element that makes so much sense. Thank you its exactly what I needed!!