# Dynamically defining height of div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I'm developing a web app with Bootstrap, idangero.us swiper and leaflet.js. I'm having a nav-bar (50px) on top and an id="swiper-area" below, which should take "height: 100% - height of navbar". I'm doing this with CSS:

```
#swiper-area {
height: calc (100% - 50px);
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
}
```

This works fine in desktop-browsers. But most mobile browsers (especially Android) can't interpret CSS calc, and that's messing up my map.

How can I achieve this behaviour with jQuery? Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: why dont you look out for media queries..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719602/setting-width-calc-with-jquery/22719707#22719707

Answer (score 1):

100% is 100% of something. 
but of what? Of your elements parent node.

You therefore would want to fine element's parent's height first:

`$("#swiper-area").parent().height()`

and then subtract 50 and set it as ur elements height.

In one line it would be:

`$("#swiper-area").height(
$("#swiper-area").parent().height()-50);`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using `.css` in jQuery, check following code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var main=jQuery("#swiper-area").height();
   var res=main-50;
  jQuery(".your_class").css("height",res)
 });
```

you can also do this by using media queries

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try these solutions!